# ESI cache on specific route

Tags: symfony, varnish, esi

How could I get varnish to cache a dynamic menu in its different state?

My current project (based on Symfony 2.8) uses the `KnpMenuBundle` and varnish to cache pages. It also make use of `ESI` in order to disable cache one specific element on some pages. Among those is the menu. But since this is not an element that changes much, I was wondering if it would be possible to cache the different states of the menu and pass the relevant one to the page currently calling the menu.

The main files involved are the following:

main.html.twig

```
{{ render_esi(controller('AppBundle:Menu:mainESI')) }}
```

AppBundle\Controller\MenuController.php

```
    public function mainESIAction($path = null)
    {
        return $this->render('menu/main_menu_esi.html.twig', [
            'path' => $path
        ]);
    }
```

menu/main_menu_esi.html.twig

```
    {{ knp_menu_render('main-menu', {'template':'menu/main_menu.html.twig'}) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

For Varnish, the url will be the same, so it will render the same.

Apply your logic outside and add a parameter to your route :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {% set menu_mode = 'admin' %}
{% else %}
    {% set menu_mode = 'normal' %}
{% endif %}

{{ render_ssi(controller('AppBundle:Menu:mainESI',{'menu_mode':menu_mode}))  }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed a confirmation on that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about Symfony, but in general, if you are able to get required state from cookies, you can try this scenario:

in recv():

- parse Cookie header and extract your state to custom request HTTP header, let's say "X-Menu-Mode: admin"
- drop all cookies

in hash():

- add that header to hash (there is URL and Host by default AFAIK)

in miss/pass (3.x) or backend_fetch (4.x):

- reconstruct Cookie header in bereq from X-Menu-Mode
- drop X-Menu-Mode from bereq

I've used this scenario with great success. ESI included fragment is now fully cacheable with different version served to each unique cookie value.

Answer (score 1):

So this was possible after all. the solution for my needs is the following one:

1. Pass the current path through twig:

AppBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig

```
{{ render_esi(controller('AppBundle:Menu:mainESI', { 'currentPath': currentPath })) }}
```

2. Get the variable in te controller action:

AppBundle/Controller/MenuAdminController.php

```
public function mainESIAction($currentPath = null) 
{
    return $this->render('menu/main_menu_esi.html.twig', [
         'currentPath' => $currentPath,
    ]);
}
```

3. Use a Matcher/Voter class:

AppBundle/Matcher/Voter/PathVoter.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Matcher\Voter;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface;
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * Class PathVoter
 */
class PathVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    protected $uri;

    /**
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function setRequest(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        if (($request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest())) {
            $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
            $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();

            if (!empty($pathInfo) && '/_fragment' === $pathInfo && !empty($request->attributes->get('currentPath'))) {
                $this->uri = $request->attributes->get('currentPath');
            } else {
                $this->uri = $pathInfo;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ItemInterface $item
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function matchItem(ItemInterface $item)
    {
        $uri = $item->getUri();

        if ((null === $this->uri) || (null === $uri)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($item->getUri() === $this->uri) {
            return true;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

4. Register the Voter

AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    app.menu.voter.class: AppBundle\MenuBundle\Matcher\Voter\PathVoter

services:
    app.menu.voter:
    class: %app.menu.voter.class%
    calls:
        - [setRequest, [@request_stack]]
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.voter }
```